# :hover and :hover:before not working properly

Tags: html, css, hover

I've gone through a lot of the resolved questions with a similar title but nothing I try seems to work.

I want the `ava.png` image to redirect to another page, but on hover I want a `:before` image (`ava_background_hoover.png`) to show up.

I may be going about it all wrong, but this is what I have so far:

```css
#slide1 {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 147px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  z-index: 100;
}

#slide1:hover {
  position: relative;
}

#slide1:hover:before {
  content: url("https://www.upload.ee/image/6050956/ava_background_hoover.png");
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

#slide2 {
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

#slide3 {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<section id="header">
  <div class="inner">
    <img id="slide1" src="https://www.upload.ee/image/6050955/ava.png"/><img id="slide2" src="https://www.upload.ee/image/6050954/arrow.png" width="140" height="160" alt=""/>
  </div>
</section>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/37qbwo66/)

Comment: the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements are used to insert content before, or after, the content of an element . `img` doesn't have content. so you can't use `pseudo-elements` on `img` . i will try to make a solution for you

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me out. I'll look forward to your solution, Mihai.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `#slide1:before`'s content as the default image. Then, on `:hover`, change the `content` attribute to the hover image.

If you do so, you need to change the `img` to a `div` (or `span`, just not an `img`).

```css
#slide1 {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 147px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  z-index: 100;
  display:inline-block;
}

#slide1:before {
  content: url("https://www.upload.ee/image/6050955/ava.png");  
}

#slide1:hover {
  position: relative;
}

#slide1:hover:after {
  content: url("https://www.upload.ee/image/6050956/ava_background_hoover.png");
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

#slide2 {
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

#slide3 {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<section id="header">
  <div class="inner">
    <a id="slide1" href="http://google.com" target="_blank"></a>
    <img id="slide2" src="https://www.upload.ee/image/6050954/arrow.png" width="140" height="160" alt=""/>
  </div>
</section>
```

Working demo including the link: http://output.jsbin.com/cudimos

Comment: But that replaces the ava image, which it shouldn't. I want the content that is visible before the :hover to remain visible upon hover. If that makes sense.

Comment: I didn't understand this from your question. I was updated my answer. Check if it answer you.

Comment: @MoshFeu i edit your code
https://jsfiddle.net/1js7urrh/ i think he want some thing like this

Comment: Thanks @kuchar, I will let him explain himself (because I'm not sure what he wants.

Comment: My mistake #slide1:before is no needed https://jsfiddle.net/1js7urrh/1/

Comment: It needed if you don't want to specify the `width` and the `height` of the `div` (Just like in case of `img`).

Comment: yes you are totally right, i mean in my example isnt needed :P I gave you voteup nice edited, he just have to position it as he want.

Comment: Thank you Mosh Feu and Kuchar, I used the code you guys provided and it's exactly what I was after. Is it possible to make the ava.png redirect to a different page though, without messing up what I have now?

Comment: `make the ava.png redirect to a different page` what do you mean? when user click on that image?

Comment: Yeah I want ava.png to have a href to a new page.

Comment: @Narc i think better way for that is use javascript. You should show `div` that contain `ava.png` after hover on `#slide1`
`onmouseover="document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';"`
and then use `onmouseout`

Comment: You can replace the `div` with `a` - so simple (and SEO friendly) :). See my updated answer.

Comment: ah i thought that you want 2 links on hover hehe @MoshFeu gave good answer

Comment: Thanks guys, looks perfect now! Solved.

Answer (score 1):

the `:before` and `:after` `pseudo-element`s are used to insert **content** before, or after, the content of an element . `img` doesn't have **content**. so you can't use `pseudo-elements` on `img` .

instead, you should use `<div>` with ids `#slide1` and `#slide2` in which you put `img` or use `background-img` on that `divs` , you choose.

i made a simple example below. click to show snippet. let me know if it helps

P.S. you can position the `:before` how you want. i just guessed how you wanted it

```css
#slide1,#slide2 { display:inline-block}

#slide1 {
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 147px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 z-index: 100;

 }
 
 #slide1:hover {
 position: relative;
 }
 
 #slide1:hover:before {
 content: url("https://www.upload.ee/image/6050956/ava_background_hoover.png");
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
    right: -150%;
    bottom: -150%;
 }
```

```html
<section id="header">
            <div class="inner">
            <div id="slide1">
            <img  src="https://www.upload.ee/image/6050955/ava.png"/>
                  
            </div>
                 <div id="slide2">
      <img src="https://www.upload.ee/image/6050954/arrow.png" width="140" height="160" alt=""/>
            </div>
      
 </div>
   </section>
```

Comment: That's what I'm after indeed, apart from the location of the hover content. But that's a easy fix. I'll try that in my code see if it works!

Comment: yeah. i just guessed how you wanted it to be positioned :) let me know if it works :D